# Nested entity in request body is ignored

Tags: spring-mvc

The domain model is

- An industry has many companies
- A company belongs to an industry

So I have my entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Industry {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Company.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "industry")
    private Collection<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // Getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Industry industry;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
public class CompaniesController extends ControllerBase {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Company create(@RequestBody Company company) {
        company.getIndustry();  // returns null
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I send request `POST /companies` with request body

```
{
  "name": "Walmart",
  "industry": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

I found that `company.getIndustry()` always returns `null`. How can I make the controller accept nested entities?

Comment: It looks like you seem to assume that this request associates the the company with the industry having the id 1. That wouldn't work, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by _of course_?

Answer (score 0):

Entities are session based. They usually work on basis of Lazy loading I.e only the first level is loaded and other attributes are loaded on Demand. You cannot pass it from one layer to other. (service to controller)

The correct way to do it. Have a Value object (a simple class) n the controller. Use it between front end and back end. Send the same value object to service. And use the entity only between Service and DAo layer

public class CompanyVO{

```
private Long id;

private String name;


private IndustryVO industryVO; // create similar class

// Getters and setters
```

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
public class CompaniesController extends ControllerBase {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Company create(@RequestBody CompanyVO companyVO) {
    companyVO.getIndustry();  // returns null
    // ...
}
```

}

Comment: I know that but I just feel DTO's (or VO's) are annoying even evil because they force you to copy and paste everything from entities. P.S., this issue has nothing to do with using entities to receive request bodies. It's all about the JSON deserialization. P.S.P.S. entities are NOT session based.

Comment: "Session" here means not "HTTP Session".

Comment: If you mean "database session", then an entity can be attached to a session, but not necessarily so.

Comment: @Aetherus _" I just feel DTO's (or VO's) are annoying"_ So your decisions are based on feelings rather than facts? _"they force you to copy and paste everything from entities"_ No. They force you to think about the client's needs.

Comment: @zeroflagL If I implement data sanitization in entities themselves, do I still need those verbose DTO's? DTO's are nothing but rubbish that forces you to copy almost everything from entities only for getting rid of a few fields that should not be updated by clients. They are even worse than `Map`s because they can't even distinguish between _a field should be updated to null_ and _a field should not be updated_. The number of DTO classes tends to inflate. I never use DTO's.

Comment: @Aetherus _"they can't even distinguish between a field should be updated to null and a field should not be updated"_ I didn't know that you don't have REST services. That could explain your aversion towards DTOs.

Comment: I would not even choose Java if I had choice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you need another Spring message converter instead of the default one. Just add **jackson** to your `pom.xml` and Spring will use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `jackson-databind` (v2.8.4) is included by default, but it doesn't help. I have to use the lame `java.util.Date` instead of `LocalDateTime` then remove the configuration file.

Comment: Where you used `DateTime`? Didn't mention in your code. Please clarify, it may help others